# Geofence works but after a while stops triggering

Tags: android, performance, android-geofence, android-intentservice, android-doze

My Geofence is working at start but then all of a sudden after a day or two stops triggering, is there a problem on Google side here or my code?

Upon boot and starting the app I use an IntentService that then registers a Geofence:

```
public class RegisterGeoIntentService extends IntentService implements 
GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
    GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, ResultCallback<Status> {

private static final String TAG = "RegisterGeoIS";

private static final long TIME_OUT = 100;
protected GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
protected ArrayList<Geofence> mGeofenceList;
private PendingIntent mGeofencePendingIntent;

public RegisterGeoIntentService() {
    super(TAG);
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    Log.i(TAG, "Creating Register Geo Intent service");
    mGeofenceList = new ArrayList<Geofence>();
    mGeofencePendingIntent = null;
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    buildGoogleApiClient();
    populateGeofenceList();
    mGoogleApiClient.blockingConnect(TIME_OUT, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    String connected = mGoogleApiClient.isConnected() ? "connected" : "disconnected";
    Log.i(TAG, "Restoring geofence - status: " + connected);

    String mode = null;
    if(intent != null) {
        mode = intent.getStringExtra(GEOFENCE_MODE);
        if(mode.equals(GEOFENCE_MODE_START)) {
            removeGeofencesButtonHandler();
            addGeofencesButtonHandler();
        } else {
            removeGeofencesButtonHandler();
        }
    } else {
        Log.e(TAG, "No Intent data, could not start Geo");
    }
}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Connected to GoogleApiClient");
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Connection suspended");
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Connection failed: ConnectionResult.getErrorCode() = " + result.getErrorCode());
}

@Override
public void onResult(Status status) {       // Not used, using await
    if(status.isSuccess()) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Geofences added");
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    } else {
        Log.i(TAG, "Geofences not successful");
        String errorMessage = GeoErrorMessages.getErrorString(this, status.getStatusCode());
        Log.e(TAG, errorMessage);
    }
}

public void addGeofencesButtonHandler() {
    if(!mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.not_connected), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }
    Status result = null;
    try {
        result = LocationServices.GeofencingApi.addGeofences(
            mGoogleApiClient,
            getGeofencingRequest(),
            getGeofencePendingIntent()
        ).await(TIME_OUT, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    } catch (SecurityException securityException) {  // TODO Catch if manually disabled
        // Catch exception generated if the app does not use ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission.
        logSecurityException(securityException);
    }
    if(result != null) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Trying to add Geofences - result: " + result.toString());
    } else {
        Log.i(TAG, "Trying to add Geofences - result: is null");
    }
}

public void removeGeofencesButtonHandler() {
    if(!mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.not_connected), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }
    Status result = null;
    try {
        result = LocationServices.GeofencingApi.removeGeofences(mGoogleApiClient, getGeofencePendingIntent()
        ).await(TIME_OUT, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    } catch (SecurityException securityException) { // TODO Catch if manually disabled
        // Catch exception generated if the app does not use ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission.
        logSecurityException(securityException);
    }
    if(result != null) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Trying to remove Geofences - result: " + result.toString());
    } else {
        Log.i(TAG, "Trying to remove Geofences - result: is null");
    }
}

private GeofencingRequest getGeofencingRequest() {
    GeofencingRequest.Builder builder = new GeofencingRequest.Builder();
    // The INITIAL_TRIGGER_ENTER flag indicates that geofencing service should trigger a
    // GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER notification when the geofence is added and if the device
    // is already inside that geofence.
    builder.setInitialTrigger(GeofencingRequest.INITIAL_TRIGGER_ENTER);
    builder.addGeofences(mGeofenceList);
    return builder.build();
}

private PendingIntent getGeofencePendingIntent() {
    if(mGeofencePendingIntent != null) {
        return mGeofencePendingIntent;
    }
    // We use FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT so that we get the same pending intent back when calling
    // addGeofences() and removeGeofences().
    // Removed, using Broadcast now
    // Intent intent = new Intent(this, GeoTransitionsIntentService.class);
    // return PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    Intent intent = new Intent("com.xyz.app.ACTION_RECEIVE_GEOFENCE");
    return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
}

private void logSecurityException(SecurityException securityException) {
    Log.e(TAG, "Invalid location permission. You need to use ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION with geofences", securityException);
}

public void populateGeofenceList() {
    RealmHelper realmHelper = RealmHelper.getInstance(this);
    for(Map.Entry<String, LatLng> entry : realmHelper.queryLandMarks().entrySet()) {
        mGeofenceList.add(new Geofence.Builder()
        .setRequestId(entry.getKey())
        .setCircularRegion(
            entry.getValue().latitude,
            entry.getValue().longitude,
            Constants.GEOFENCE_RADIUS_IN_METERS)
        .setExpirationDuration(Geofence.NEVER_EXPIRE)
        .setTransitionTypes(Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER | Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT)
        .build());
    }
}

protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
        .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
        .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
        .addApi(LocationServices.API)
        .build();
}
}
```

And this:

```
public class GeofenceReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
...

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
this.context = context;

GeofencingEvent geofencingEvent = GeofencingEvent.fromIntent(intent);
if(geofencingEvent.hasError()) {
    String errorMessage = GeoErrorMessages.getErrorString(context, geofencingEvent.getErrorCode());
    Log.e(TAG, errorMessage);
    return;
}

int geofenceTransition = geofencingEvent.getGeofenceTransition();

if(geofenceTransition == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER || geofenceTransition == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT) {

// Do stuff
}
...
```

Also see my answer what I tried and thought I fixed. But it did not help.

Comment: *I have tried to disable DozeMode for this app* that is not possible

Comment: Under Android, Settings, Battery, Battery Optimization, All apps... select and Don't optimize in Nexus 6P

Comment: That doesn't do what you think it does. You cannot disable doze mode for an app

Comment: And this https://commonsware.com/blog/2015/11/11/google-anti-trust-issues.html you can manually add an permission and request it.

Comment: You might be right I rephrased the question a bit...

Comment: Have you tried tying your GoogleApiClient to the application context by doing `new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getApplicationContext())` instead of `new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Please note this did actually not help*

My GeoFence was always triggered but the IntentService was the problem

```
private PendingIntent getGeofencePendingIntent() {
    if(mGeofencePendingIntent != null) {
        return mGeofencePendingIntent;
    }
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, GeoTransitionsIntentService.class);
    // We use FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT so that we get the same pending intent back     when calling
    // addGeofences() and removeGeofences().
    return PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
}
```

changed to using an BroadcastReceiver defined in AndroidManifest as

```
private PendingIntent getGeofencePendingIntent() {
    if(mGeofencePendingIntent != null) {
        return mGeofencePendingIntent;
    }
    // We use FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT so that we get the same pending intent back when calling
    // addGeofences() and removeGeofences().
    // Removed, using Broadcast now
    // Intent intent = new Intent(this, GeoTransitionsIntentService.class);
    // return PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    Intent intent = new Intent("com.xyz.myapp.ACTION_RECEIVE_GEOFENCE");
    return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
}
```

Comment: Don't make accept your own answer if it is not working/correct. Wait till you received the right solutions from others.

Comment: As I mentioned, I thought I fixed it but it was not the solution (and I can't delete this answer, having said that it is part of the story).

Comment: Perhaps an admin can help out

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem on Oreo, using getApplicationContext() solved it.